# how to add a Label and button in grid layout with user input in kivy python

Tags: python, mobile, kivy, android-gridlayout

I am new to kivy ...I wanted make a to do list app....and wanted to add a name of the task from user and a button which can get a tick mark on press....

some how i got the thing to get a label on screen but i couldn't get it.

This main.py

```
class ListWidget(RecycleView):

    def update(self):
        self.data = [{'text': str(item)}for item in self.item]


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.item = []

class RootWidget(BoxLayout):

    inputbutton = ObjectProperty(None).

    inputcontent = ObjectProperty(None).

    outputcontent = ObjectProperty(None).

    def add_item(self):
        if self.inputcontent.text != " ":
            formatted = f'\n*{self.inputcontent.text}'
            self.outputcontent.item.append(formatted)
            self.outputcontent.update()
            self.inputcontent.text = ""

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return RootWidget()

MyApp().run()
```

this is my.kv file

```
<RootWidget>

    inputbutton: inputbutton

    inputcontent: inputcontent

    outputcontent: outputcontent

    orientation: 'vertical'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: 1, 0.25

        Label:
            text: 'TO-DO'
            font_size: 32
            size_hint: 1,0.3

        BoxLayout:

            orientation: 'horizontal'

            Button:
                id: inputbutton
                size_hint: 0.25, 1
                text: 'add'
                on_press:root.add_item()

            TextInput:
                id: inputcontent
                multiline: False



    ListWidget:
        id: outputcontent
        viewclass: 'Label'
        orientation: 'vertical'


        RecycleBoxLayout:
            default_size: None,dp(56)
            default_size_hint: 0.4,None
            size_hint_y: None
            height:self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'
```

this is the output
[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nvglu.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom `viewclass` that does what you want. Something like this:

```
class LabelAndButton(GridLayout):
    text = StringProperty()  # must have a text property (used in ListWidget.data)
```

Then in the `kv` you can use this class as the `viewclass` and define how it looks:

```
    ListWidget:
        id: outputcontent
        viewclass: 'LabelAndButton'  # use the new class
        orientation: 'vertical'


        RecycleBoxLayout:
            default_size: None,dp(56)
            default_size_hint: 0.4,None
            size_hint_y: None
            height:self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'
            
<LabelAndButton>:
    cols:2
    Label:
        text: root.text
    Button:
        text: root.text
```